# Swift availability check exclude macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, conditional-compilation

I have a code in my app which I want to execute on iOS 13 or later. So, I was using a standard availability check:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    return Color.systemGray6.resolvedColor(with: trait!)
} else {
    return Color(red: 0.082, green: 0.118, blue: 0.161, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

`Color` is a typealias which casts to `UIColor` on iOS and `NSColor` on macOS. I am kind of trying to create macOS version of my target with as little `if..else` as possible.

The code above should work as `NSColor` has many of the same init methods as `UIColor`. The problem is that when I build my macOS target it complains about `systemGray6`. So, for a reason unknown to me, macOS target passes `#available(iOS 13.0, *)` check!

Why does it happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` you're basically saying: do this on iOS 13.0 and later, *and on all other operating systems* - that's what the `*` means.

In your specific case, you'll need to exclude macOS, since NSColor does not have the `systemGrayX` getters:

```swift
#if os(iOS)
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
     return Color.systemGray6
}
#endif
return Color(red: 0.082, green: 0.118, blue: 0.161, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Wanted to avoid using `#if`s, but you've rightly pointed out that `else` is unnecessary given the `return` statement. No way I guess to specify iOS only in the `#available` check? :)

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: would be nice to be able to use `#available(iOS 13, !macOS, *)`

Comment: Hopefully, we will get this ability soon: https://forums.swift.org/t/ability-to-exclude-certain-platforms-in-availability-check/36573

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare like this:

```
#if os(macOS)
    import AppKit
    public typealias Color = NSColor
#else
    import UIKit
    public typealias Color = UIColor
#endif
```

And then you can use Color in both iOS and MacOS:

```
Color.Black // will work for both
```

Comment: How would it help me with Color.systemGray6 which I want to make available only on iOS starting from 13.0?